# Plot datetime series as categorical data in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

**TLDR: What I'm looking for is a way to plot a list of timestamps as equidistant datapoints, with `mpl` deciding which labels to show.**

If equidistant plotting of timestamped datapoints is only possible by turning the timestamps into strings (and so plotting them as a categorical axis), my question could also be phrased: **how can one get `mpl` to automatically drop labels from an overcrowded categorical axis?**

---

**Details:**

I have a timeseries with monthly data, that I'd like to plot as a bar graph. My issue is that `matplotlib.pyplot` automatically plots this data on a time axis:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, )
s = pd.Series(range(3,7), pd.date_range('2021', freq='MS', periods=4))
ax.bar(s.index, s.values, 27) # width 27 days
ax.set_ylabel('income [Eur]')
```

[image]

Usually, this it what I want, but with monthly data it looks weird because Feb is significantly shorter. **What I want is for the data to be plotted equi-distantly. Is there a way to force this**?

Importantly, I want to retain the behaviour that e.g. only the second or third label is plotted once the x-axis becomes too crowded, without having to adjust it manually.

What I've tried or don't want to do:

- I could make the gaps between the bars the same - by tweaking the width of the bars. However, I'm plotting revenue data [Eur], which means that an uneven bar width is misleading.
- I could turn the timestamps into a string so that the data is plotted categorically:

```py
s = pd.Series(range(3,7), pd.date_range('2021', freq='MS', periods=4))
x = [f'{ts.year}-{ts.month:02}' for ts in s.index]
ax.bar(x, s.values, 0.9) # width now as fraction of spacing between datapoints
```

[image]

However, this leads `mpl` to think each label must be plotted, which gets crowded:

```py
s = pd.Series(range(3,17), pd.date_range('2021', freq='MS', periods=14))
x = [f'{ts.year}-{ts.month:02}' for ts in s.index]
ax.bar(x, s.values, 0.9) # width now as fraction of spacing between datapoints
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for converting the type of the data from custom to category type?

Comment: Thanks for you comment. No; if I do that, every label will always be displayed. I'd like to convert them to a numerical value that is represented by a custom label, if something like that is possible. So that, just like with any other numerical axis, a label spacing is used that fits on the available space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can space out your categorical ticks with the [`MaxNLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator).

- Given your bigger Series sample with categorical labels:

  ```
  s = pd.Series(range(3,17), pd.date_range('2021', freq='MS', periods=14))
  x = [f'{ts.year}-{ts.month:02}' for ts in s.index]

  fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  ax.bar(x, s.values, 0.9)
  ax.set_ylabel('income [Eur]')
  ```
- Apply the [`MaxNLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator) with a specified number of bins (or `'auto'`):

  ```
  from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

  locator = MaxNLocator(nbins=5) # or nbins='auto'
  ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
  ```

  [image: MaxNLocator with 5 bins or auto bins]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @tdy, however, this solution still uses a datetime axis. The months are spaced according to their duration, as can be seen esp between Feb and March. -- I'm looking for a solution that plots the months evenly spaced (as I achieved by defining `x`) but that also drops labels if there are too many, as (unlike in a 'normal' categorical axis), missing values can be deduced.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it a bit clearer what it exactly is that I'm looking for.

Comment: @ElRudi ah gotcha, then i believe you're looking for the [MaxNLocator](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator) (answer updated)